# Adding data-remote="true" after the page has rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Is there a way to have the `data-remote="true"` tag be picked up by `rails.js` after the document has already loaded?

I have a form that is normally not remote. But in a certain case I want to render that form to a page dynamically and have that form be submitted via AJAX. I tried adding the tag onto the form once it has been rendered to the page, but it looks like `rails.js` only picks up on elements with that tag on the initial DOM load.